# Show the derivative is bounded

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f: (0, \infty)$ such that:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt x }}\left( {\sin \frac{1}{x} + 1} \right) + \sqrt x \left( { - \frac{1}{{{x^2}}}} \right)\cos \frac{1}{x}$$

Now, We can bound it by:

$$\left| {f'(x)} \right| \le \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{1} \cdot 1 = 2$$

This part of proof is from a book. Now, it's a bit unclear to me how it was done. Just be observing the derivative and familiarity with trigonometry?

Comment: I think you need some restrictions on $x$, specifically that $x\geq 1$ (we seem to be assuming that $2\sqrt x > 2$ for instance).

Comment: You right. Added. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the bounds require $x \ge 1$.

$\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ are bounded above by $1$ and below by $-1$.  That accounts for the trig terms.

$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x \ge 1$

Finally, $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x^2} = x^{-3/2}$ is bounded above by $1$ for $x \ge 1$.

Comment: it is required for $x\gt 0$, but i guess it doesn't matter. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is bounded as $x\to0$....